# How to mock a directive, testing Angular 6 component with Jasmine and Karma

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocking

I'm trying to test a component. This component is dependents on a directive that called Megazord. I need some syntax help on how to use a mock directive.

Example of using services as mock:

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [..., MegazordCanvasDirective],
  providers: [
    {provide: UserService},
    {provide: HttpClient, useClass: HttpClientMock}, // Mock
    {provide: Router, useClass: RouterMock}, // Mock
  ]
}).compileComponents();
```

This is my TestBed Config:

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations: [..., MegazordCanvasDirective],
  ...
}).compileComponents();
```

The test:

```
it('should select level3', () => {
    const level3Mocks = createMockLevel3();
    component.onSelectLevel3(level3Mocks[0]);
    // expect(component.selectedLevel3).toBe(level3Mocks[0]);
    // expect(component.mode).toBe('tagging');
  });
```

The directive dependency:

```
@ViewChild(MegazordCanvasDirective) public megazord;
```

The method:

```
public onSelectLevel3(level3: Level3): void {
    this.mode = 'tagging';
    this.updateMegazord(); // This one is using Megazord Directive.
    this.manager.clearSearchResults();
    this.onSelectLevel1(level3.level1.id);
    this.onSelectLevel2(level3.level1, level3.level2);
    this.selectedLevel3 = level3;
  }
```

updateMegazord method:

```
private updateMegazord(): void {
    this.megazord.api.toggleCanMask(this.mode === 'masking');
    this.megazord.api.toggleCanTag(this.mode === 'tagging');
  }
```

The Error:

[image]

Comment: Do you call `fixture.detectChanges();` in beforeEach function?

Comment: @J.S. Yes I do.

`beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TrainingTaskComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    element = fixture.nativeElement;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
`

Comment: Then you should try to override the component attribute to mock it e.g: `component.megazord = {api: { toggleCanMask: ()=> {}}}`

Answer (score 0):

J.S. helped me via a comment:

> Then you should try to override the component attribute to mock it
>   e.g:

`component.megazord = {api: { toggleCanMask: ()=> {}}}`

**It's working, thank you.**